# JavaFX 8: Custom controller from an inner class

Tags: java, javafx

**The Problem**

I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to use the custom controller inside `Joystick.java`.
Here is my file hierarchy:

```
--view
----MainWindow.java
----mainWindow.fxml
----Joystick
------Joystick.java
------joystick.fxml
```

In `mainWindow.fxml`, I have the lines:

```
<?import view.Joystick.Joystick?>
...
    <Joystick fx:id="manualJsk" layoutX="459.0" layoutY="195.0" />
```

I want to display my custom controller, but I keep getting the `ClassNotFoundException`, despite importing it.
Interestingly, everything works if I move the file to the `view` package:

```
--view
----MainWindow.java
----mainWindow.fxml
----Joystick.java
----Joystick
------joystick.fxml
```

... which makes me think the `import` is bad. Why could that be?

**The Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: view.Joystick$Joystick
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 15 more
```

Edit:
**Joystick Code**:

```
public class Joystick extends Pane {
    public Joystick() {
        super();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("joystick.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`joystick.fxml`

```
<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" type="javafx.scene.layout.Pane">
    <children>
        <Button text="Click Me"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Is the inner-class non-static? If so, you'd need to define your own factory for the controller, as I don't believe the loader supports inner classes. Please post relevant code.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It is, I just added the code. What do you mean by a factory/static? I know what both of those things are, but I don't understand specifically what do you mean I should write. Could you provide a small example or a link to a guide or something?

Comment: `Joystick` is an inner class? What is the enclosing class? Or is `Joystick` also the name of a package? It's not clear what the setup is here.